# MouseDown/MouseUp and Click events out of sync

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-8.1

I have a winforms app, that catches MouseDown, MouseUp and Click events.

Clicking the form slowly (once a second or so) and the event counters stay in sync.

Clicking quickly and the down/up event tallys keep track, but click event tally falls behind:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private int clicks = 0;
    private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        clicks++;
        textBox1.Text = clicks.ToString();
    }

    private int mdown=0;
    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mdown++;
        textBox2.Text = mdown.ToString();
    }
    private int mup = 0;
    private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mup++;
        textBox3.Text = mup.ToString();
    }
}
```

[image]

Reading docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171542.aspx this doesn't seem possible - am i missing something obvious

(This happens when using trackpad buttons or external bluetooth mouse, so hopefully this is a programming error and not an issue with the machine.)

EDIT 
Damien is of course correct, tracking double clicks as well and everything stays in sync:

```
    private void Form1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        clicks++;
        textBox1.Text = clicks.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: What reason could you possibly have for using *all three* of these events at the same time? MouseUp is the customary way to handle click events.

Comment: Thanks for responding @CodyGray - The above program just highlights the issue - i was just catching click events and noticing they where not always registering, so i created the above as an example. Sure i could just move to tracking MouseUp, but i would like to work out **why** i get the above results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because sometimes you're clicking fast enough that you're triggering double-clicks. Consider the sequence from the documentation page you linked to:

> Following is the order of events raised for a double mouse-button click:
>
> 1. MouseDown event.
> 2. Click event.
> 3. MouseClick event.
> 4. MouseUp event.
> 5. MouseDown event.
> 6. DoubleClick event. (This can vary, depending on whether the control in question has the StandardDoubleClick style bit set to true. For more information about how to set a ControlStyles bit, see the SetStyle method.)
> 7. MouseDoubleClick event.
> 8. MouseUp event.

And notice that there are twice as many `MouseDown`/`MouseUp` events in that sequence as there are `MouseClick` events.